Are there risks to a power amplifier by driving it below its minimum frequency?
I have an RF power amplifier that is rated for operation between 700 and 2700 MHz. What happens if we drive it at a lower frequency, say 600 MHz? Is there an increased risk in damaging the amplifier? Does this depend on the class of amplifier?
Our specific amp is the Mini-Circuits HPA-272+ (minicircuits.com/WebStore/dashboard.html?model=HPA-272%2B) but I'm curious about power amplifier operation in general. I appreciate that we might have significant noise coming out of the amp based on the answers to this question:
Why do amplifiers have minimum frequencies?

It depends on the type of amplifier. If it uses an inductive load (such as class C and class E amplifiers), running at too low a frequency will almost definitely damage it.

Certain types of amplifiers can be damaged by driving them below the designed frequency.
The high-efficiency C and E amplifier classes both have a power stage that looks like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
It should be pretty clear from just looking at the schematic that running at too low of a frequency will result in much too much current through Q1; in the extreme case, L1 is functionally a short circuit at DC, so holding Q1 on continuously would quite clearly destroy it. Other inductive-load amplifiers, like H-bridge type ones that have a transformer primary directly across the bridge, would have similar issues.
Even when this isn't an issue, though, running at too low an operating frequency can cause problems in other ways. The output matching network is designed to be a good match to 50 Ω line (or 75 Ω line, or whatever impedance your system might be) at a certain range of frequencies, and outside that range--both above and below it--the VSWR will go way up. This means power gets reflected back into the amplifier instead of going to the load, causing in extreme cases the same sort of problems you get from running the amplifier without a load.
It seems unlikely to me, though, that either of these issues would cause immediate destruction of a 700-2700 MHz amplifier running at 600 MHz. There may be reduced efficiency and increased heating (make sure it's well heatsinked), and you probably won't achieve the rated gain of the amplifier, but you're not operating so far out of the designed band that I would expect catastrophic issues. Don't take this to mean it'll definitely be fine, though--it very well could still break things!

Thank you, Hearth. We hooked the amp up to a network analyzer (appropriately attenuated), swept the input from 100 MHz to 2 GHz, and slowly brought the power up. Focusing on the lower frequency performance, we could see that the gain peaked at 700 MHz although it was still ~40 dB. The frequencies below 700 MHz were also the first to show compression as power increased. So while the amp works at 600 MHz your comment reminds us to be aware that the hardware may not be happy to do this. But no magic smoke so far.
